# How to compare the stored procedure's output?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures, sqlparameter

I want to check first if the user exists or not so I made a stored procedure in my SQL Server to check that.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Login
    @username varchar(20), 
    @password varchar(20),
    @status int output
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT username, password 
               FROM SystemUser 
               WHERE username = @username AND password = @password)
        SET @status = 1
    ELSE
        SET @status = 0
```

Then, using ASP.NET Webforms, I'm creating a login page for the users

```
protected void login(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String connstr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sports"].ToString();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            
    String username = txt_Username.Text;
    String password = txt_password.Text;

    SqlCommand login = new SqlCommand("userLogin", conn);
    login.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    login.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", username));
    login.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", password));

    SqlParameter loginstatus = login.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Int);
    loginstatus.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    conn.Open();
    login.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    if (loginstatus.GetInt32 == 1)
    {
        Response.Write("hello");
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
    }
}
```

However, I get an error:

> Error CS1061  'SqlParameter' does not contain a definition for 'GetInt32' and no accessible extension method 'GetInt32' accepting a first argument of type 'SqlParameter' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any idea how can I compare the output from the stored procedure in the if condition?

Thanks in advance

I tried different types of methods like `.value`.
Expecting to know how to compare the value to an int.

Comment: NEVER ever store passwords in a database. Use a salted hash instead.

Comment: I'm a 3rd-year computer engineering student and this is a small project that we are working on, we are not experts we don't know what salted hash is but I appreciate the advice I will google what salted hash is. Thanks, mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the value using `.Value`

```
if ((int)loginstatus.Value == 1)
{
    ...
}
```

There are other issues also in your code.

you are storing the password as plain text in a database table.

please use `using` with `SqlConnection`  to dispose of automatically, same comment for `SqlCommand` .

and please use meaningful names when declaring variables like `SqlCommand login`. it's very unclear by the name `login`. it should be `command` or `sqlCommand`

Comment: This solved my problem thanks so much, I will consider googling 'using' to enhance the code.